# Rank multiple string columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data frame I am working with has three columns named `list1`, `list2` and `list3` based on three separate lists of "best places to live".

**Desired output:**

I want to return another column, series or groupby which shows the overall rank for each city after it takes into account position across all lists so `Edingburgh` would top the list and others would follow based on how close they are in terms of ranking to the top of each column.  To clarify, Edingburgh is ranked 1st in `list2` and `list3`.

It will look something like this:

```
1 Edingburgh 
2 Hart 
3 Orkney, London, Solihull 
4 Rutland, Bristol Hertfordshire 
5 Wychavon, Newcastle, Northumberland
```

Basically I want to see the overall ranking for each city when all lists have been taken into account and learn how this can be achieved with Pandas.

**What have I tried?**

I was hoping there would be a simple way to rank using something like `places2live.rank()` but do not see how I could use this with string values.

**Data**

```
    list1      list2        list3
0   Hart       Edinburgh    Edinburgh
1   Orkney     London       Solihull
2   Rutland    Bristol      Hertfordshire
3   Wychavon   Newcastle    Northumberland
4   Winchester Manchester   South Lanarkshire
5   Wokingham  Glasgow      Berkshire
6   Waverley   Leeds        Darlington
7   Craven     Cardiff      North Lanarkshire
```

Comment: Can you show us your expected out put ?

Comment: @Wen please see updated desired output section.  Thanks

Comment: I would create another dataset that contains just the unique values of `[list1, list2, list3]` (i.e. each city), and then set `list1` in this new dataset equal to the row number where the city is found in `list1` in the original dataset. Repeat this for `list2` and `list3`. Then, for each city, compute the average of `list1`, `list2`, and `list3`, and then arrange the new dataset by the newly created `avg_rank` variable.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you are generating the output, can you describe the steps you are taking to create the overall rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
cities = pd.Index(np.unique(df.values))
ranks = pd.Series([1] * len(cities), index=cities)

for column in df:
    ranks = ((ranks + df.reset_index().set_index(column)['index'])/2).fillna(ranks)

city_ranks = ranks.reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].apply(list).reset_index(drop=True)
city_ranks.index += 1
print(city_ranks)
```

[output]

```
1                                    [Edinburgh]
2                                         [Hart]
3                     [London, Orkney, Solihull]
4              [Bristol, Hertfordshire, Rutland]
5          [Newcastle, Northumberland, Wychavon]
6    [Manchester, South Lanarkshire, Winchester]
7                [Berkshire, Glasgow, Wokingham]
8                  [Darlington, Leeds, Waverley]
9           [Cardiff, Craven, North Lanarkshire]
```